# Extending base_url() to base_url_admin() not working properly in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My config **config_backend.php** (autoloaded) looks like this:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['my_admin_url'] = 'admin';
```

My helper **admin_helper.php** looks like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function base_url_admin()
{
    $ci =& get_instance();

    $ci->config->load('config_backend');
    $ci->load->helper('url');

    return base_url().$my_admin_url.'/';
}
```

My code in the view looks like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url_admin(); ?>">Admin</a>
```

But the problem is that instead of the correct output like:

```
<a href="http://localhost/admin">Admin</a>
```

The link looks like:

```
<a href="http://localhost">Admin</a>
```

Funny thing is that when I do in helper e.g. this:

```
function base_url_admin()
{
    $ci =& get_instance();

    $ci->config->load('config_backend');
    $ci->load->helper('url');

    return "idiot";
}
```

it outputs something like:

```
http://localhost/admin/idiot
```

So, I assume that admin_helper is loaded, but I don't know how the admin appear there?

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to return the `my_admin_url` config because you are not picking up the config item, you expect it to return it and/or the config returns a variable under the array key name i.e. `$my_admin_url`. But to return it, you can do this:

```
return base_url() . $ci->config->item('my_admin_url') . '/';
```

Comment: Wow, it's working , thanks. Only for other people change the $this to $ci when using helper function. Also these two lines `ci->config->load('config_backend');
    $ci->load->helper('url');` are not necessery in helper.